# Finding determinant of 4*4 Matrix via LU Decomposition?

Tags: calculus, matrices

What is the **shortcut way** of finding the determinant of a 4 by 4 matrix (and I assume this applies to any n by n square matrix greater than 2) once you have found an LU or PLU decomposition?

Given that det(A)=det(P)det(L)det(U) or det(A)=det(L)det(U) (if no permutation matrix was necessary).

Here is a PLU decomposition example:
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=LU+decomposition+of+%7B%7B4%2C3%2C2%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C10%2C3%2C4%7D%2C%7B5%2C3%2C2%2C-4%7D%2C%7B4%2C8%2C7%2C9%7D%7D

The determinant of that matrix is 602. If I recall, one is supposed to multiply the diagonal entries of the Upper Matrix starting from row 1, column 1 (which gets me -602) and then...    magic? What happens from there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to have the right ideas.  Here's the gist:

- Any permutation matrix has determinant $\pm 1$, depending on the parity of the permutation
- To find the determinant of an upper triangular or lower triangular matrix, take the product of the diagonal entries.
- If $A = PLU$, then $\det(A) = \det(P)\det(L)\det(U)$

In your example, $P$ has determinant $-1$, $L$ has determinant $1$ (since each diagonal entry is $1$), and $U$ has determinant $-602$, as you indicated. So, the determinant of the product is the product of the determinants which is $602$.

Comment: This brings me to my next question, is there also a shorthand way of finding the determinant of the permutation matrix? In the example I linked, how do you determine if it is +1 or -1 at a glance?

Comment: The easiest method I know is the following: find the number of row switches and column switches it takes to get to the identity matrix.  If the number is even, the determinant is $1$.  If the number is odd, the determinant is $-1$.

Comment: In this case, we can make the permutation into the identity as follows: switch columns 1,2; switch columns 2,4; switch columns 3,4.  That's $3$ switches.  $3$ is odd, the determinant is $-1$.

Comment: Thank you so much. You've really helped me a lot.